# PowerShell retrieve 3 characters after match

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to match 3 characters after in a string using PowerShell. Example:

```
$servername1 = "z002p002dcs001"
$serverName2 = "z002p003dcs001"
$servername3 = "z002p004dcs001"
```

I am only interested in the 3 digits after `p`, so `002`, `003`, `004`. I know regex is required here but I'm stuck.

```
$serverName1 -match "p002*"
True
```

Good

```
$serverName1 -match "p003*"
True
```

Bad

What am I doing wrong? Why does `"p003*"` return a match for `$serverName1`?

Comment: This part `3*` repeats 0 or more times a 3 so `p003*` will match 00 in 002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the asterix (`*`) character at the end. Simply removing it will fix your problem. e.g.

```
$serverName1 -match "p002"
True
$serverName1 -match "p003"
False
```

The reason why your second example returned `True` is because the asterix (`*`) character is regex for "0 or more". So what you are matching is:

```
p   - Matches "p"
0   - Matches "0"
0   - Matches "0"
3   - Matches "3"
 *  - Quantifier, matches 0 or more of the preceding token. e.g. "3"
```

This means that anything with "p00" will match.

Edit:

Going beyond, if you are interested in the 3 digits after the "p" you can use a capture group and a character set:

```
"p([0-9]{3})"

p       - Matches "p"
 (      - Start of Capture group
  [0-9] - Character set. Match digits 0-9
   {3}  - Quantifier, matches 3 of the preceding token e.g. any digit 0-9
 )      - End Capture group
```

Also, in PowerShell, you can then use the special `$Matches` variable to extract the number:

```
$regex = "p([0-9]{3})"

$servername1 = "z002p002dcs001"
$serverName2 = "z002p003dcs001"
$servername3 = "z002p004dcs001"

$serverName1 -match $regex
$Matches[1]
002

$serverName2 -match $regex
$Matches[1]
003

$serverName3 -match $regex
$Matches[1]
004
```

Answer (score 2):

The ' * ' character means match anything preceding it 0 or more times. The ' * ' here would be inappropriate.

I am not exactly sure what you want to match, but `p[0-9]{3}` might be a better pattern.

One could execute `$Matches` to see what was matched previously to get an idea of what's happening.

Reference: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html
https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Hal's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61392501/45375), given that in the question's title you say you want to *retrieve* 3 characters (digits):

```
PS> 'z002p002dcs001',
    'z002p003dcs001',
    'z002p004dcs001' -replace '.+p(\d{3}).+', '$1'
002
003
004
```

This uses PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) via a regex that matches the input in full and replaces it with the 3 digits (`\d{3}`) that follow the (last) `p` character; in other words: it extracts the 3 digits that follow the (last) `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk in regex means 0 or more instances of previous character. Here, 3 is before asterisk and has 0 instances so it matches. "+" matches 1 or more instances of previous character. So correct regex is "p003.+".